# WPF: can I call a method from the xaml file that is in another class?

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, function-call

I am working on a WPF project, and I implemented the MVC -Pattern for my application .
So I have the MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs as the View, and then a Controller and a Model class (first time that I did this).
Everything works great so far. But here is what i don't like:
When I have an event defined in the xaml file, lets take:

```
<Button Content="Save" Click="SaveButton_ClickEvent"/>
```

then whenever the Save Button is clicked, the function in the xaml.cs file is called:

```
private void SaveButton_ClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Controller.Save();
}
```

I actually have a lot of those functions in the xaml.cs file, where there is a function that just calls another fuction in the controller, and it seems kind of wasteful to me. Isn't there a better way of doing this?
I think I have read somewhere that if one implements the MVC-pattern in WPF, the xaml.cs file stays almost empty.
So my question is:

Is there a way to call a Method in my controller (or any other) class from within the .xaml file wihtout putting a function in the xaml.cs file? (and if yes, how would i do that)

Or did I get it all wrong and this is all done differently?

Comment: You would not need to have the SaveButton_ClickEvent handler method when you would implement MVVM and bind the Button's Command property to an ICommand property in the view model.

Comment: Thats good to know for the next time. But I was just told to do it with MVC, and I would have to learn MVVM first to do it.

Comment: *"I have read somewhere that if one implements the MVC-pattern in WPF, the xaml.cs file stays almost empty."* - This *can* be the case. Depending on your application there can be quite a lot of code in the .xaml.cs file. Your statement has the same quality as saying that when implementing MVC a class has one constructor. MVC doesn't care if your code is in a .cs, .xaml.cs or .xaml file. It doesn't care about writing particular code in C#, XAML or TypeScript. There is a lot of UI logic that you can't implement using XAML. If this is the case, then you would have to use C#.

Comment: *"I actually have a lot of those functiuons in the xaml.cs file, where there is a function that just calls another fuction in the controller, and it seems kind of wasteful to me. Isn't there a better way of doing this? "* - Nothing wrong with that. However, you could implement an ICommand in your Controller and bind it to the Button.Command property instead of handling the Button.Click event.. Both solution, command or event, are equally fine. You very likely can replace most method calls by using data binding.

Comment: Data binding and commands are like events framework/library specific and not design pattern specific. MVC and MVVM are not so different. You don't need MVVM in order to implement ICommand a have some other objects call ICommand.Execute on the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to implement the recommended MVVM design pattern and replace the event handler with a binding that binds the `Command` property of the `Button` to an `ICommand` property of a view model, you could for example implement an [attached behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) that handles the `Click` event and calls your controller:

```
public static class Mvc
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Click", typeof(string), typeof(Mvc),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnChanged));

    public static string GetClick(Button obj) =>
        (string)obj.GetValue(ClickProperty);

    public static void SetClick(Button obj, string value) =>
        obj.SetValue(ClickProperty, value);

    private static void OnChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValue as string)
            && obj is Button button)
        {
            button.Click += OnButtonClick;
        }
    }

    private static void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        object controller = button.DataContext;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            string methodName = GetClick(button);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName))
            {
                controller.GetType()
                    .GetMethod(methodName)?
                    .Invoke(controller, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="Save" local:Mvc.Click="Save"/>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Controller();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller
{
    public void Save()
    { 
        //save... 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very impressed with this solution. This does what i asked for, so i will except it. But it is not simpler than the mentioned function calls in the MainWindows.xaml.cs. Another disadvantage is that I can't use the Model class as a datacontext anymore. I guess WPF is simply not made to do what I asked for.